# Problema con obtencion de datos

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

estoy haciendo una APP de escritorio. Es unaa aplicacion para hacer el registro de alumnos en una academias.

Tengo un problema al obtener la direccion, hice una funcion para validar el CP y la colonia del alumno, esta funcion realiza bien su lavor cuando la ejecuto en un script aparte, pero cuando la integro a la APP, unicamente funciona cuando el resultado de la consulta es uno.

Adjunto el codigo de la funcion y fotos de como funciona. Agradeceria mucho su ayuda :)

```
from SQL import Conexion
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox,ttk

#Creamos la conexion con la base de datos
Conexion = Conexion.Conectar()

#Obtenemos la base de datos
DB = Conexion[0]
#Obtenemos nuestro puntero
Puntero = Conexion[1]

def Direccion(codigo,city):
    #Creamos una clave de CP
    CodigoP = codigo
    Ciudad = city

    if Ciudad == 'CDMX':
        #Hacemos la consulta de SQL
        Puntero.execute('''SELECT * FROM CDMX WHERE CP = ?''',(CodigoP))

    elif Ciudad == 'EDO':
        #Hacemos la consulta de SQL
        Puntero.execute('''SELECT * FROM CDMX WHERE CP = ?''',(CodigoP))

    Direcciones_Obtenida = Puntero.fetchall()

    if len(Direcciones_Obtenida)>1:
        #Creamos una lista donde vamos a guardar nuestra direccion
        Colonias = []

        for i in Direcciones_Obtenida:
            Colonias.append(i[1])

        def seleccionar_opcion():
            seleccion = seleccion_var.get()
            return(seleccion)

        def InsertarDireccion():
            Dic = seleccionar_opcion()
            Mensaje = '''COLONIA SELECCIONADA : {}'''.format(Dic)
            messagebox.showinfo(message = Mensaje)

        root = Tk()
        root.title("Ejemplo de RadioButtons")

        seleccion_var = StringVar()

        for opcion in Colonias:
            radio_button = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text=opcion, variable=seleccion_var, value=opcion, command=seleccionar_opcion)
            radio_button.pack(anchor=W)

        Registro = Button(root,text = 'Realizar registro',command = InsertarDireccion)
        Registro.config(font =('Interval Sans Pro Cond Bold Italic',9,'bold'))
        Registro.pack(anchor='s')

        root.mainloop()

    elif len(Direcciones_Obtenida)==1:
        Dic = Direcciones_Obtenida[0][0:3]
        Mensaje = '''COLONIA SELECCIONADA : {}'''.format(Dic)
        messagebox.showinfo(message = Mensaje)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Me parece que la explicación que das no deja ver claramente el problema que tienes. Quizás falta explicar cómo el código falla o qué es exactamente lo que esperas que pase y no está pasando, o si tienes un mensaje de error, cuál es ese error exactamente y en qué momento ocurre. Para más información lee [ask].